# How to plot 3D graph of function of two variables in R

Tags: r, plot, graph, 3d

my task is to plot function of two variables f(x,y), where m is maturity and goes from 1 to 15. Here is my code:

```
f<-function(x,y)((x -y * ((1 - exp(-m / 4)) / (m / 4)) - 0.035 * ((1 - exp(-m / 4
  )) / (m / 4) - exp(-m / 4)))) 
z <- outer(x, y, f)
persp(x, y, z)
open3d()
plot3d(f,xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "m", ylim = c(-1, 1), xlim = c(-1, 1), zlim = c(1, 15))
```

But 3D grpah looks like this:[image]

Can anyone tell, where I made mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass a function as an argument of `plot3D`. Instead pass, your variable `x`, `y` and `f(x,y)`. Here a simple reproducible example

```
set.seed(5)
x <- runif(100)
m <- 4
f<-function(x,y)((x -y * ((1 - exp(-m / 4)) / (m / 4)) - 0.035 * ((1 - exp(-m / 4
)) / (m / 4) - exp(-m / 4)))) 
z <- f(x,y)
library(rgl)
open3d()
plot3d(x,y,z,xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "m")
```

Which give you

[image]

if you another `type` of simbol to plot your data look at the `type` argument of `plot3D`. By default is set to `"p"` which means "points" but there are methods for "lines", "segments", sphere ecc (see `?plot3D`):

> type
> For the default method, a single character indicating the type of item to plot. Supported types are: 'p' for points, 's' for spheres, 'l' for lines, 'h' for line segments from z = 0, and 'n' for nothing. For the mesh3d method, one of 'shade', 'wire', or 'dots'. Partial matching is used.

Comment: You set m <- 4, but m should go from 1:15, is it okay then?  Is there any way how to display function, not as dots, but as a solid part?

Comment: you can plot a `plot3D` for each value of `m`, but I don't think it is possible to plot them all together. For the solid part, I edit my answer to include the possibilities offered by `plot3D`